# How to make JavaScript code more bullet-proof?

Tags: javascript, web, typescript

I come from a compiled-language background (C/C++/Objective-C) and am currently writing a full-fledged application in JavaScript. (TypeScript actually, but my question is the same for both.)

The problem I'm running into is that if a single error occurs, the entire flow of execution halts. For instance, if I have:

```
myFunction()
{
    doSomethingA();
    doSomethingB();
    doSomethingC();
}
```

then if doSomethingA() has something like this:

```
var myValue = window.myData.myValue;
```

but "myData" doesn't exist on "window" at the time, then all code STOPS EXECUTING... doSomethingB() and doSomethingC() do not execute, and a console error is logged. That might be fine for simple web pages, but I'm creating an application, and it needs to not 'stop working' inexplicably.

Granted, I can use try/catch to be 'aware' of this error, but that STILL doesn't solve my problem: I would like to write the code in a way such that doSomethingB() and doSomethingC() continue to execute, even if a problem arises.
However, this is a huge over-simplification of my code. Imagine there are MANY of these functions. It would be impractical to surround each with its own separate try/catch block. Even if I did, I need *the rest* of a given function to continue to execute even if something in the first part fails.

Of course, I can 'protect' my variables by using:

```
if ( typeof window.myData != "undefined")
```

or

```
if (window.myData.hasOwnProperty("myValue")
```

but that becomes very messy if you have several levels to check, such as when accessing:

```
var myValue = window.myData.something.anotherLevel.somethingElse.value;
```

Now I have to check if myData, something, anotherLevel, and somethingElse are all valid before accessing this value 'safely'. This results in very ugly code.

Is there a better way to make my code more 'bullet-proof'? If a property is unexpectedly missing, I need code to *continue* executing after the problem statement. Is that possible without 'protecting' every single statement that accesses data that has even a tiny chance of being undefined?

Comment: You could create a function called $assign that does all necessary checking, a la `$assign(myValue, window.myData.something.anotherlevel.value);` or, perhaps better, `var myValue = $checkValue(window.myData.something.anotherlevel.value)`.

Comment: The [next version of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#user-content-20) will come with non-nullable types. :)

Comment: nothing is bullet proof if you use large enough bullets fired from a large enough gun  (humor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just how JavaScript is. It's not a strongly-typed language. You have the right approach checking for falsy/undefined. You could look into a utility library, something like Lodash's `isUndefined()` method to help ease the pain a bit. They have a lot of helper methods like that such as checking for object types, arrays, object literals, etc.

https://lodash.com/docs#isUndefined

Comment: exactly! lodash has _.isEmpty(), _.isUndefined() but to get result we have to make a hell of nesting if()-s. to avoid it there is _.get(object, path, [default]) it takes object and looks for path and if it does not exist returns undefined or default value  (:

Comment: @num8er yup! lodash is great! :)

Comment: The `isUndefined` Underscore/lodash API saddles you with the performance cost of an extra function call with zero benefit over using the simple expression `x === undefined`.

Comment: @CSnover I would argue the performance overhead is so minimal, that the benefits gained from readability/clarity outweigh it. And besides, the OP already knows about that sort of typechecking. The point of this post isn't to praise the isUndefined() method but rather to demonstrate utility libraries which incorporate typechecking functionality useful to OP (like nested property checking).

Answer (score 3):

Normally You have to have some set of "nested if hells" like:

```
if(typeof window.myData !== 'undefined' && typeof window.myData.something !== 'undefined' && typeof window.myData.something.anotherlevel !== 'undefined' ...) {

}
```

To ease developers pain there is utilities for example [lodash](http://lodash.com)

it's very helpful and shortens Your code.

it has [_.get(object, path)](https://lodash.com/docs#get)  function that takes element by path and if not found it just returns undefined.

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.13.1/dist/lodash.js"></script>

<script>
  window.myData = {
    something: {
      anotherlevel: {
        value: 'YOU GOT ME! (:' 
      },
      zerolevel: {
        value: 0
      }
    }
  };

  function getDataByPath(path) {
    var result = _.get(window, path);
    alert(result);
  }
</script>

<button onclick="getDataByPath('myData.something.anotherlevel.value')">
  anotherlevel.value
</button>

<br/><br/>

<button onclick="getDataByPath('myData.something.zerolevel.value')">
  zerolevel.value
</button>

<br/><br/>
<button onclick="getDataByPath('myData.something.unexistentlevel.value')">
  unexistentlevel.value
</button>
```

Comment: Ohhh... How I love to answer to funny questions. @Bálint if value is 0 it will return 0. it only returns undefined if the path really does not exist. FYI, I've added 3rd button to answer for value: 0 example, click "RUN CODE SNIPPET"  (:

Comment: You still don't understand. What happens if in the if statement `if(window.myData){...}`, window.myData is 0? It won't run, because 0 is a falsey value.

Comment: And I'm speaking about the "if hell" solution

Comment: @Bálint, when You write anything, type it normally, You said: this is not good approach. 1) read question it's an example, in real it will be even longer, 2) real solution is after it.

Comment: Updated answer exclusively for You @Bálint :) Next time just click edit and type Your fix there and become coauthor of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to check, if the variables you use are undefined or not with

```
typeof window.yourVariable === "undefined"
```

It's however not very safe to rely on variables in the window object, use scopes and closures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm accepting Prefix's answer, since I don't like accepting my own answers. And, it's useful to hear about the Lodash helper, and know that the "nested if hells" I have are a normal (sad to hear it!) part of JavaScript.

However, the 'solution' I've gone with that has ended up making me feel very happy, is to actually reject a premise in my original question: that try/catch is not a good solution.

Turns out try/catch, combined with attempting to make sure variables are undefined, is a good way to catch those cases that I've missed.

I've actually ended up architecting it as follows. Let's say I have lots of functions I want to happen as a result of doStuff(), and I've put them into window.callbacks. I can then do (untested pseudocode, but it gives you the gist of it):

```
doStuff() {
   for (var myFunc in window.callbacks) {
       if (window.callbacks.hasOwnProperty(myFunc) ) { 
            try {
              window.callbacks[myFunc].call();
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log("%cCaught error in " + myFunc + ": " + (err.stack || err), 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
            }
       }
   }
}
```

This logs a unique console log message, complete with stack trace, showing what triggered the error, and yet CODE EXECUTION CONTINUES. Subsequent callbacks will still be called. The only code that doesn't execute is the remainder of the callback that caused the error.

Given my compiled-language background, this gives me warm fuzzy feelings... it means that at worst, a tiny function will fail to execute, not an entire code path following an error.